# What happened to FM Radio in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

FM Radio was a mandatory HW requirement in Windows Phone 7, but it's not present on any current Windows Phone 8 device.
Why there is no FM radio in Music Hub in WP8? Can we at least use the [FMRadio API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.radio.fmradio%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)?

Comment: It's kind of a weird downgrade, even though it's understandable as an FM radio is becoming a less used thing by the day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206947(v=vs.105).aspx

> Windows Phone 8 does not support the FM radio feature. If you use the
>   FM radio API in a Windows Phone 8 app, a RadioDisabledException will
>   occur.

Also from what I heard:

> ...the FM radio feature was planned to be included but got cut from this
>   release due to stability vs. time constraints.
>   (... I don't know if
>   there are any plans to re-enable this feature in a future update.)

You can use this test to safely determine if FMRadio can be used on current phone:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Flag is radio device is available in this phone.
/// </summary>
public bool IsRadioAvailable
{
    get
    {
        if (!radioInitialized)
        {
            radioInitialized = true;
            try
            {
                radio = FMRadio.Instance;
                isRadioAvailable = true;
            }
            catch (RadioDisabledException e)
            {
                isRadioAvailable = false;
            }
        }
        return isRadioAvailable;
    }
}
private bool radioInitialized;
private bool isRadioAvailable;

private FMRadio radio;
```

**Update:**
[According to various sources](http://www.theverge.com/2013/5/14/4327026/nokia-lumia-windows-phone-update-fm-radio-july) FM radio will be enabled in upcoming Windows Phone 8 update that should arrive in Summer 2013.

Answer (score 0):

I read that the Lumia 920 has FMRX and just needs to be "utilised". Not sure if they helps in any way

Answer (score 0):

[FM Radio returns](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/basics/windows-phone-8-update-history), on supported hardware, in Windows Phone 8 'GDR2' (8.0.10327.77/78).

It's not clear whether the API support also returns and how it behaves:

> #### Caution:
>
> FM radio is supported only in apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1.
>   If you use the FMRadio class in apps that target Windows Phone OS 8.0
>   or later, a RadioDisabledException indicates that the FM radio feature
>   is not available. On Windows Phone 8 devices with a build of 8.0.10322
>   or greater, the run-time exception may not occur if you use the
>   FMRadio API. However, the FMRadio API is not supported for apps that
>   target Windows Phone OS 8.0.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.radio.fmradio.frequency(v=vs.105).aspx

In other words, there is no Windows Phone Runtime API to control the radio.

I've just tried out an FM Radio app from the store, which does work.